# UserManager.CreateAsync() inserting child objects into database which already exist in databse. ASP.Net Identity Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have AppUser class

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }       
    public int DesignationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Designation Designation { get; set; }     
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }        
}
```

and Designation class

```
public class Designation
{
  public int Id { get; set; }   
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and AppDbContext class

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>, 
        UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }        

    public DbSet<Designation> Designations { get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);          

        builder.Entity<UserRole>(userRole => 
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new {ur.UserId, ur.RoleId});

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();                
        });         
    }
}
```

in UserController class register method is like

```
 [HttpPost("register")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(userForRegisterDto);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);   

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {               
           return Ok();
        }        

        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
```

I have used Dtos and AutoMapper for mapping Dtos to models. Mapping has no problem

while trying register new user with already existed Designation(I have seeded designations to database) this error has thrown **"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Designations'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Designations'. The duplicate key value is (6).The statement has been terminated."**

while debugging i found that the error is coming from

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);
```

I have tried to use `EntityState.Unchanged` for child object as seen in other Questions&answers from StackOverFlow. But i don't understand where to put this code, becuase i didn't extend UserManager class and I don't want to create my own UserManager class. `UserManager<AppUser>` is working fine for other implementation of my App except for `userManager.CreateAsync()` method.

Comment: Does the primary key have value in `userToCreate`?Maybe you could  set auto increment to 1 for PK  field in db:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?view=aspnetcore-2.1#value-generated-on-add-data-annotations

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I seem to have stumbled upon it myself.